# Conditional expectation, show two random variables are equal almost surely.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

$
\newcommand{ \F }{ \mathcal{F} }
\newcommand{ \prob }{ \mathbb{P} }
\newcommand{ \G }{ \mathcal{G} }
\newcommand{ \L }{ \mathcal{L} }
\newcommand{ \exp }[1]{ \mathbb{E}\left[ #1 \right] }
\newcommand{ \ind }[1]{ 1_{ #1 } }
$

> $\exp{X|Y}=Y \text{ almost surely}$ and $\exp{Y|X}=X \text{ almost surely}.$
>
> Show that $P(X=Y)=1$.

**Attempt**

I know that if $X \in \L^1(\Omega, \F,\prob)$, $\G \subset \F$ then there exists $Y$ that is (i) $\G$ measurable, (ii) $\exp{|Y|} < \infty $ (iii) $\exp{ Y \ind{ F} }= \exp{ X \ind{G } } $ for all $G \in \G$.

\begin{align}
P(X=Y)=1 &\Leftrightarrow P(X \neq Y ) = 0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow P( \{X<Y\}\cup\{Y<X \}) =0\\
&\Leftrightarrow P(X<Y) + P(X>Y) =0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow P(X<Y) = P(X>Y) =0 \\
\end{align}

I am not sure where to go from here.